# Is it the latest version? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, package, dependencies, pubspec.yaml

When I have to use a package, I'm going to **pub.dev** and look for it.

[pub.dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksgGo.png)

Once I got it, I click on the **installing** tab.

[Installing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZMOf.png)

Then I got the package's latest version and I add it to the **pubspec.yaml**

[pubspec.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPIbo.png)

I've seen plenty of times **another way** of adding a package to the pubspect.yaml:

[another way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aInGj.png)

I wonder if this way also refers to the package's latest version.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: [Please post code/errors/etc as formatted text instead of links to images of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

It does not mean the latest version. It means 'any' version. The good way to check installed version is to look into `pubspec.lock` file, it contains locked information about installed dependencies, their checksums etc.

For example, I have got installed `path_provider` package with version 2.0.12 in my project. It is not in `pubspec.yaml`, but it is required by other package in `pubspec.lock`. So, after adding `path_provider:` to `pubspec.yaml` its version is still the same - 2.0.12 and not latest (2.0.13). That's because 'any' version is satisfied by 2.0.12.